# What is the motive behind the redundant entry in both easy-install.pth and *.egg-link?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, setup.py

I was trying out python setup tools .

I did using pbr .My code is https://github.com/HarishAtGitHub/doc/tree/master/Pythonsetuptools/pbr

I did

```
python setup.py develop
```

and found the entry to my package both in

1) easy-install.pth

2) *.egg-link

what is the motive behind having the same location reference in *.egg-link when entry in easy-install.pth is what is required .

Even when I remove *.egg-link, packages are still importable , then what purpose does it serve to have the link in egg-link file in dist-packages ?

I searched and found http://www.ianbicking.org/docs/setuptools-presentation/ slide number 11 and found

> develop installs a package without moving it into site-packages/
>
> Paste.egg-link is the poor man's symlink to ~/co/paste
>
> easy-install.pth also points to ~/co/paste Python finds .pth files in
>   site-packages and adds their contents to sys.path

But I still cannot understand why we need entry in *.egg-link when it can work without that ?

Answer (score 2):

## Performance

You're right there is some duplication there.  All folders in `easy-install.pth` come from `.egg-link` files.

You can consider `easy-install.pth` to be a de-duplicated list of the folders you can find in the egg links.  These folders are added to `sys.path`.  This is a form of caching -- you avoid having to scan all the egg-link files every time.

#### Package identity vs module location

You can't simply eradicate the egg-link files either because they represent *packages*.  This is how `pip` finds out if a given package is installed or not.  See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/42583363/1075152.

#### Example: single folder with multiple packages

Let's say you installed two packages 'a' and 'b' in editable mode, and they both are located in the same folder.

```
/path/to/my_packages/a/__init__.py
/path/to/my_packages/b/__init__.py
```

You now have *one* entry in `easy-install.pth` (where both *modules* can imported from) but you have *two* `.egg-link` files (one for each *package*).

#### Example: package with a name different from the module

Say you have a package named `mycompanystoolbox`.  It contains code that offers the `toolbox` module, without the `mycompanys` prefix -- so you can `import toolbox`.

You now have a file `mycompanystoolbox.egg-link` representing the package, and a folder in `easy-install.pth` from which `toolbox` module can be imported.