# Check whether a python package has been installed in 'editable' (egg-link) mode or not?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

Is there any way to check whether a Python package has been installed normally (`pip install` / `setup.py install`) or in editable/egg-link mode (`pip install -e` / `setup.py develop`)?

I know I could check whether the path to the package contains `site-packages` which would most likely mean it's a "non-editable" install, but this feels extremely dirty and I would rather avoid this.

---

The reason I'm trying to check this is that my application is checking for config files in various places, such as `/etc/myapp.conf` and `~/.myapp.conf`. For developers I'd like to check in `<pkgdir>/myapp.conf` but since I show the list of possible locations in case no config was found, I really don't want to include the pkgdir option when the package has been installed to site-packages (since users should not create a config file in there).

Answer (score 4):

`pip` contains [code](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/0964c9797c1e8de901b045f66fe4d91502cc9877/pip/utils/__init__.py#L318-L324) for this (it's used by `pip freeze` to prefix the line with `-e`). Since `pip`'s API is not guaranteed to be stable, it's best to copy the code into the own application instead of importing it from `pip`:

```
def dist_is_editable(dist):
    """Is distribution an editable install?"""
    for path_item in sys.path:
        egg_link = os.path.join(path_item, dist.project_name + '.egg-link')
        if os.path.isfile(egg_link):
            return True
    return False
```

The code is MIT-licensed so it should be safe to copy&paste into pretty much any project.

Comment: any idea how can from inside `setup.py` if a `pip install -e .` is going on?

Comment: @nmz787 Maybe a bit brittle, but you could try to inspect `sys.argv` and look for a `-e`. It will work most of cases, but not if the `-e` is specified in a requirements file.